# Not showing 10 random boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(function() {
    max = 25;
    min = 1;
    var i = 0;

    do {
        var match = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (max - min )- min);

        $('td').each(function() {
            i++;
            console.log( match );   
            if (i == match) {
                $(this).addClass('active');
            }       
        })
    } while ($('td.active').length == 10);
})
```

My problem is that I do not return 10 random boxes but only one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
} while ( $('td.active').length == 10 );
```

to

```
} while ( $('td.active').length < 10 );
```

`while` != `until`

But if you have less than 10 `td`, you'll loop indefinitely.  And it will very often break as `i` always grows bigger.

I think you want this :

```
$(function() {
    var max = 25; // don't forget the "var", if you don't want to declare global variables
    var min = 1;
    do {
        var match = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (max - min )- min);
        $('td').eq(match).addClass('active');
     } while ($('td.active').length < 10);
})
```

Comment: when i change the browser crashes

Comment: @NikiLichev There was another logical problem that I fixed. See edit

Answer (score 0):

Try this : if you are sure that their are minimum 10 td's

```
   $(function() {
    max = 25;
    min = 1;
    var i = 0;
    var y=0;

    do {
        var match = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (max - min )- min);

        $('td').each(function() {
            i++;
            console.log( match );   
            if (i == match) {
                $(this).addClass('active');
                y++;
            }       
        })
    } while (y<10);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said much about what the code is attempting to do, but in addition to the other suggestions, I think you also mean

```
var match= Math.ceil(Math.random() * (max - min )+ min);
```

Note the '+ min' instead of minus.